# Shift entire TikZ-picture vertically into part of align environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to move a TikZ-picture upward so that it eliminates the amount of space taken up for my solution. How can I move the TikZ-picture upward (just a bit) **into** the align-environment?
FYI, the following is the exam problem.

> "The midpoint of the line segment from $(-2,1)$ to a point $P$ is $(1, -1)$. Determine the coordinates of $P$."

The following is my solution to the exam problem.

```
Let $P = (x,y)$. We need to find $x$ and $y$. We have
\begin{align*}
\text{Midpoint} = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)
\quad   &\implies \quad
(1,-1) = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)\\
&\implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    1 = \frac{-2 + x}{2}\\
    -1 = \frac{1 + y}{2}
\end{dcases}\\
&\implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    2 = -2 + x\\
    -2 = 1 + y
\end{dcases}
\quad \implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    x = 4\\
    y = -3.
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}
%\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}{        %DO I NEED THIS?
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.5]
% Draw grid lines
\draw[help lines] (-2.5,-3.5) grid (4.5,1.5);
% Draw x-axis
\draw[very thick,->] (-3,0) -- (5.5,0)
    node[right] {\large $x$}; 
% Draw y-axis
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-4) -- (0,2.5) 
node[above] {\large $y$};
% Special points
\node[above, fill=SolutionColor] at (-2,1) {$(-2,1)$};
\fill (-2,1) circle (4pt);
\node[right, fill=SolutionColor] at (1.5,-1) {$(1,-1)$};
\fill (1,-1) circle (4pt);
\node[right, fill=SolutionColor] at (4,-3) {$P$};
\draw (-2,1) -- (1,-1) -- (4,-3);
\fill[red] (4,-3) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{minipage}%    DO I NEED THIS?
```

[image]

Comment: A complete working example is preferable.

Comment: As Altermundus said, you should make sure your code is complete and compilable. In this case, one had to figure out that the code needs the `tikz` and `mathtools` packages, the `arrows` library, and some custom colour. It's always best to include the necessary preamble, so others can just copy and paste the code into a new document without having to make any adjustments.

Answer (score 8):

This is a job for Martin Scharrer's excellent `adjustbox` package: It allows (among many other things) to trim the top off a box (which can contain, among many other things, a `tikzpicture`), so its official height is smaller than the actual height of the content.

If you wrap your `tikzpicture` in `\begin{adjustbox}{trim=0 0 0 2.5cm} ... \end{adjustbox}`, you'll get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
Let $P = (x,y)$. We need to find $x$ and $y$. We have
\begin{align*}
\text{Midpoint} = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)
\quad   &\implies \quad
(1,-1) = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)\\
        &\implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    1 = \frac{-2 + x}{2}\\
    -1 = \frac{1 + y}{2}
\end{dcases}\\
        &\implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    2 = -2 + x\\
    -2 = 1 + y
\end{dcases}
\quad \implies \quad
\begin{dcases}
    x = 4\\
    y = -3.
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\begin{adjustbox}{trim=0 0 0 2.5cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.5]
% Draw grid lines
\draw[help lines] (-2.5,-3.5) grid (4.5,1.5);
% Draw x-axis
\draw[very thick,->] (-3,0) -- (5.5,0)
    node[right] {\large $x$}; 
% Draw y-axis
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-4) -- (0,2.5) 
node[above] {\large $y$};
% Special points
\node[above, fill=white] at (-2,1) {$(-2,1)$};
\fill (-2,1) circle (4pt);
\node[right, fill=white] at (1.5,-1) {$(1,-1)$};
\fill (1,-1) circle (4pt);
\node[right, fill=white] at (4,-3) {$P$};
\draw (-2,1) -- (1,-1) -- (4,-3);
\fill[red] (4,-3) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use `\useasboundingbox`. You need to find the dimensions of the rectangle to place the picture correctly.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}
 Let $P = (x,y)$. We need to find $x$ and $y$. We have
 \begin{align*}
 \text{Midpoint} = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)
 \quad   &\implies \quad
 (1,-1) = \biggl( \frac{-2 + x}{2} , \frac{1 + y}{2} \biggr)\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.5] 
 \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (7,3);        
 % Draw grid lines
 \draw[help lines] (-2.5,-3.5) grid (4.5,1.5);
 % Draw x-axis
 \draw[very thick,->] (-3,0) -- (5.5,0)
     node[right] {\large $x$}; 
 % Draw y-axis
 \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-4) -- (0,2.5) 
 node[above] {\large $y$};
 % Special points
 \node[above, fill=white] at (-2,1) {$(-2,1)$};
 \fill (-2,1) circle (4pt);
 \node[right, fill=white] at (1.5,-1) {$(1,-1)$};
 \fill (1,-1) circle (4pt);
 \node[right, fill=white] at (4,-3) {$P$};
 \draw (-2,1) -- (1,-1) -- (4,-3);
 \fill[red] (4,-3) circle (4pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}          &\implies \quad
 \begin{dcases}
     1 = \frac{-2 + x}{2}\\
     -1 = \frac{1 + y}{2}
 \end{dcases}\\
         &\implies \quad
 \begin{dcases}
     2 = -2 + x\\
     -2 = 1 + y
 \end{dcases}
 \quad \implies \quad
 \begin{dcases}
     x = 4\\
     y = -3.
 \end{dcases}
 \end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to also shift the last two `align` lines.

Comment: Yes because I placed the picture with the second `\implies` but it's possible to place it with the third `\implies`. We have the choice.

Comment: That is an excellent point, as long as one is not bothered by the additional vertical space.